# Why does GNU ld linker doesn't remember all the symbols it sees

Tags: linker, gnu, ld

When linking with GNU ld, the order is important. The dependent library must appear before the dependency.
For instance, if a function in `file1.a` calls a function in `file2.a`, then the linking order must be, non intuitively, `file1.a` then `file2.a`.  From my reading, that's because `ld` pick from a file only the symbols that it needs, meaning an unresolved symbol from a previous file.

This behavior leads to the arguably funny solution to circular dependency problems whereas if `file1::fn1()` calls `file2::fn2()` which itself calls `file1::fn3()`, then the link command must be written like this `ld -lfile1 -lfile2 -lfile1`. Even leading to cMake adding this [LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY¶](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY.html) parameter. Clearly an unoptimal solution to a problem that can't be cleanly solved due to ld design choice.

If I had to solve the problem of symbol resolution, I would probably build an index of every symbol I see first and once the index is full, I'd start the symbol resolution.

My question is, why does ld works like that? Is it only a question of reducing the memory usage by never loading unused symbols? Is there something more to it? Why is it so weirdly made?

Answer (score -1):

> For instance, if a function in `file1.o` calls a function in `file2.o`, then the linking order must be, non intuitively, `file1.o` then `file2.o`.

That is *completely* incorrect: the order of *object* files on the link line *doesn't matter*.

What you are describing is true for *archive* libraries and *only* archive libraries.

> If I had to solve the problem of symbol resolution, I would probably build an index of every symbol I see first and once the index is full, I'd start the symbol resolution.

You have to remember how *small* the memory and how *slow* the disks were when UNIX linker was created ([PDP-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-7) had a whopping 4K words of memory, expandable to 64K words). Your design would likely use 10x more memory and be 2x slower with disk access (100x slower with tape access).

Modern linkers, LLD in particular, do not care about the order. Gold does care, but only because it wanted to be compatible with the BFD linker.

Comment: I have edited my question to use the .a extension.